# How can I connect a gap in a white frame on black background with python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I developed a frame detection algorithm in python using opencv that detects a metallic frame in a rgb image. The output is a white frame on a black background. However, if the frame is partly covered, it contains gaps. How can I fill the gaps, preferably using opencv?

Example output of my algorithm:

[Frame with gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb50K.png)

Desired output:

[Frame without gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqEDR.png)

Edit:
This is how I detect the frame currently.

I have an rgb image of a crop canopy and a frame on top of it:
[Crop canopy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plIlQ.jpg)

My code detects bright parts in the image and removes noise such that only the frame should be left (which is the largest brigth object in the image). Below is a reproducible example when setting image path to the example image above:

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

kernel_size = 10
brightness_thres_low = 175
brightness_thres_high = 255
erode_it_1 = 6
dilate_it_1 = 25
erode_it_2 = 20


# read image
img = cv2.imread(image_path)

# find bright pixel values that indicate frame and set to bw
thres = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), brightness_thres_low, brightness_thres_high, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
thres = np.invert(thres)
        
# adapt image to only contain frame
kernel = np.ones((kernel_size, kernel_size), np.uint8)
img_adapted = cv2.erode(thres,kernel, iterations = erode_it_1)
img_adapted = cv2.dilate(img_adapted,kernel, iterations = dilate_it_1)
img_adapted = cv2.erode(img_adapted, kernel, iterations = erode_it_2)
```

If the frame is fully in the image, it gets detected fine. But as you can see in the example rgb image, part of the frame is covered by a plant. This results in an incomplete detection of the frame. I would like to fill this gap in the frame in a generic way such that it can be applied to any gap of any processed rgb image.

Comment: How do you detect the frame now? Do you want to share some reproducible code and a sample image so others can work with it?

Comment: I edited the original post with additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code you can start with:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

kernel_size = 10
erode = 2
thres_low = 175
thres_high = 255

img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thres = cv2.threshold(gray, thres_low, thres_high, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = np.ones((kernel_size, kernel_size), np.uint8)
thres = cv2.erode(thres, kernel, iterations=erode)   # erode fine contours

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thres, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # find contours
all_contours = np.vstack(contours)   # concatenate all contours
hull = cv2.convexHull(all_contours)  # get convex hull of all contours
peri = cv2.arcLength(hull, True)     # get perimeter length of hull for the next step
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, 0.05 * peri, True)    # simplify hull
cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 10)   # draw the contour

cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! The convexHull function was the key to the solution of my problem. I can work with this further.